# Editing when you have reached you review limit

Tags: feature-request, edits, review

I reviewed my daily 20 edits this morning. I love to do it with my coffee and waffles beside me.

Now I capped the **reviewed** edits limit not the edits limit itself.
This is the tricky part : I see a suggested edit on a post like this and I read it

> [image]

I know I can't approve / reject it but I still feel it could be upgraded. So I consider adding my own edit. 
But I get stuck with this page teasing me because I reached my limit of 20 reviews ... !!

> [image]

Where is the <kbd>I don't want to review. Let me add my own Edit</kbd> button ?

Comment: What would happen to the pending suggested edit? Does it just get stomped on by your edit?

Comment: @animuson Sorry missed it.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Well it doesn't since there is no implemented way to overwrite it ( yet ? ) but yeah that's what it would do.

Comment: @animuson where are the closed votes ? You *obviously* voted for it and so did I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why it's important that suggested edits be substantive improvements to posts and not be overly minor.  Their existence prevents edits on the post until the review is approved or rejected, which can prevent a higher quality edit from being made.

Fundamentally there is no way for you to edit that post until the suggested edit is approved or rejected.  It's inherently impossible.  The implementation would have to be a way of letting you approve or reject the edit despite hitting your review limit (in which case, you're effectively removing the limit).  That would be...bad; there's a reason that limit is in place.

Comment: I get the reason part. But I would suggest a way to simply say let me overwrite that edit with mine. After all, it's the user's fault if he didn't make a complete edit. Also it's a little bit like the concept of "I'm currently editing and I see a pop-up that says someone else is editing and the best edit will win". But I understand.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Then you're asking for a way to reject edits even though you've hit your review limit.  The point of having a review limit is to limit the number of rejections a single user can make in a day to prevent abuse, misuse, ignorance, etc. from being too significant.  We don't want someone able to just reject every single edit that comes in because they feel mean.

Comment: It is the same thing indeed.. thanks !:) Guess I'll have to monitor that post until it gets reviewed.